# After joining two queries (each having different columns) with UNION I'm getting only one column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have joined two queries with UNION keyword (Access 2016). It looks like that:

```
SELECT ITEM.IName, Sum(STOCK_IN.StockIn) AS SumOfIN
FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOCK_IN ON ITEM.IName = STOCK_IN.IName
GROUP BY ITEM.IName
UNION SELECT ITEM.IName, Sum(STOCK_OUT.StockOut) AS SumOfOut
FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOCK_OUT ON ITEM.IName = STOCK_OUT.IName
GROUP BY ITEM.IName
```

I get the following result:

```
IName | SumOfIN
----------------
Abis Nig | 3

Abrotanum | 1

Acid Acet | 2

Aconite  Nap |  2

Aconite  Nap |  3

Antim Crud |    3

Antim Tart |    1
```

But I want the following result:

```
IName | SumOfIN | SumOfOut
----------------

Abis Nig | 3 | 0

Abrotanum | 1 | 0

Acid Acet | 2 | 0

Aconite  Nap | 2 | 3

Antim Crud | 0 | 3

Antim Tart | 0 | 1
```

Can anyone tell me what changes should I make here?

Comment: Both SELECT statements return 2 columns, how do you expect to get a 3d column? Maybe you should explain what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add dummy values for the third column where they don't exist in the table you are `UNION`ing. In addition, you need an overall SELECT/GROUP BY since you can have values for both StockIn and StockOut:

```
SELECT IName, SUM(SumOfIN), Sum(SumOfOut) 
FROM (SELECT ITEM.IName, Sum(STOCK_IN.StockIn) AS SumOfIN, 0 AS SumOfOut
      FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOCK_IN ON ITEM.IName = STOCK_IN.IName
      GROUP BY ITEM.IName
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ITEM.IName, 0, Sum(STOCK_OUT.StockOut)
      FROM ITEM INNER JOIN STOCK_OUT ON ITEM.IName = STOCK_OUT.IName
      GROUP BY ITEM.IName) s
GROUP BY IName
```

Note that column names in the result table are all taken from the first table in the `UNION`, so we must name `SumOfOut` in that query.

Comment: You need to group by After unioning to get the Op's results. You should also use UNION ALL as you know there is no need to deduplicate the results.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for that - I hadn't noticed that set of values in the question. Will edit...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this query without `UNION` at all:

```
select i.iname, si.sumofin, so.sumofout
from (item as i left join
      (select si.iname, sum(si.stockin) as sumofin
       from stock_in as si
       group by si.iname
      ) as si
      on si.iname = i.iname
     ) left join
     (select so.iname, sum(so.stockout) as sumofout
      from stock_out as so
      group by so.iname
     ) as so
     on so.iname = i.iname;
```

This will include items that have no stock in or stock out.  That might be a good thing, or a bad thing.  If a bad thing, then add:

```
where si.sumofin > 0 or so.sumofout > 0
```

If you are going to use `union all`, then you can dispense with the `join` to items entirely:

```
SELECT IName, SUM(SumOfIN), Sum(SumOfOut) 
FROM (SELECT si.IName, Sum(si.StockIn) AS SumOfIN, 0 AS SumOfOut
      FROM STOCK_IN as si
      GROUP BY si.INAME
      UNION ALL
      SELECT so.IName, 0, Sum(so.StockOut)
      STOCK_OUT so 
      GROUP BY so.IName
     ) s
GROUP BY IName;
```

The `JOIN` would only be necessary if you had stock items that are not in the `items` table.  That would be a sign of bad data modeling.